# The type 'double' must be a reference type in order to use it as parameter 'TRow'

Tags: ml.net

Using ML.Net I have (the data use is as example):

```
 MLContext context = new MLContext();

IDataView data = context.Data.LoadFromEnumerable<Double>(new List<Double> { 1, 2, 3 });
```

But I get the error:

```
The type 'double' must be a reference type in order to use it as parameter 'TRow'
```

Can't I load data only from a List of Doubles?

I am trying to forecast a time series.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can pass in raw values because the IDataView expects some sort of schema. One way you could to it without creating a new class to define the schema is to use anonymous types.

[image]